# Centering a row of elements specifically on one element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

How can I center a row of elements where I can choose which element will be the very center of the webpage? Meaning all other elements should be floating on the left or right of this center element.

I want to make the row be centered on `#itemMainPic` in this example of what I'm working with:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.itemOtherPics {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 float-left itemOtherPics"><img class="py-3 img-fluid" src="https://place-hold.it/1200x800/e600ff" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="height:300px;width=auto;"><img class="py-3 img-fluid" src="https://place-hold.it/1200x800/e600ff" type="button"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="height:300px;width=auto;"><img class="py-3 img-fluid" src="https://place-hold.it/1200x800/e600ff" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="height:300px;width=auto;"></div>
    <div class="float-none" id="itemMainPic"><img class="pr-3 img-fluid" src="https://place-hold.it/1200x800/e600ff" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="height:300px;width=auto;"></div>
    <div class="float-right">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-sbutitle">Subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/by091hqp/1/

Comment: add `margin: auto` to the `#itemMainPic`. is that the effect you need?

Comment: No, I was hoping for both elements to stick right beside the center element with same padding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking can be solved using bootstrap's flex with justify content between.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content

```css
.bd-highlight {
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3 justify-content-between">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer uses completely different markup than the OP's. Typically when answering with code, it's expected that you provide an answer that modifies OP's code to work, rather than adding an unnecessary translation step between your code and theirs.

Comment: This can't be an answer if it doesn't use the same markup.

Answer (score 0):

Add `justify-content: center` to the `row` class.

[revised fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sahbmqep/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
  <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3 justify-content-between">
    <div class="p-2 itemOtherPics"><img class="py-3 img-fluid" src="https://place-hold.it/1200x800/e600ff" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="height:300px;width=auto;"><img class="py-3 img-fluid" src="https://place-hold.it/1200x800/e600ff" type="button"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="height:300px;width=auto;"><img class="py-3 img-fluid" src="https://place-hold.it/1200x800/e600ff" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="height:300px;width=auto;"></div>
    <div class="p-2" id="itemMainPic"><img class="pr-3 img-fluid" src="https://place-hold.it/1200x800/e600ff" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="height:300px;width=auto;"></div>
    <div class="p-2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-sbutitle">Subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You may need to change out the `p-2` class to suit your needs